# Changing a field type using phpmyadmin's GUI vs using alter table produces different behavior

Tags: mysql, database, indexing, phpmyadmin

My database has two tables: payments & bookings.

payments table has half a million rows and I have this simple query:

`select * from payments where payments.booking_id in(64791, 64792,...,65791)`

inside `in` operator there are 1000 booking ids.

Here is the output of mysql's `explain`. which shows that my index on table payments is not used and instead mysql does a full scan on payments table.It takes around 800~900ms to execute.(which is a lot)

[image: Output of explain]

After some searching I found that the bookings.id field was `unsigned int(10)` while payments.booking_id was `signed int(11)`. So mysql had to do 1000 casts to `unsigned int(10)` in order to use my index.

By changing payments.booking_id field type from phpmyadmin's GUI as shown below fixes my problem.

[image: Changing payments.booking_id from phpmyadmin's graphical user interface]

Now my query uses my index and executes in 33ms

[image: explain output after booking_id change using phpmyadmin's GUI]

My problem is that when i perform the same change using mysql's alter table:

`ALTER TABLE payments CHANGE booking_id booking_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL;`

The original query keeps not using my index.

I tried

1. deleting and recreating the index
2. reseting query cache by `RESET QUERY CACHE;`
3. Restarting mysql server

without any success

I am using:

- phpmyadmin: 4.9.0.1
- mysql-server: 10.3.16-MariaDB

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an inconsistency in `NULL` vs `NOT NULL`.